# Display Suite field content type class

Tags: entities, theming, display-suite

I've created a custom field in Display Suite using this code in my module:

```
function mymodule_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
$fields = array();

$fields['node']['type_label'] = array(
  'title' => t('Label'),
  'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
  'function' => 'mymodule_ds_field_type_label',
);

function mymodule_ds_field_type_label($field) {

$entity = $field['entity'];
$content = $entity->type;

return $content;
}
```

Now, I was able to set the content of the field to match my content type, but I also want to set a dynamic class for this field equal to that content type, for example:

```
$fields['node']['type_label'] = array(
  'title' => t('Label'),
  'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
  'function' => 'mymodule_ds_field_type_label',
  'class' => 'CONTENTTYPE',
);
```

Or:

```
function mymodule_ds_field_type_label($field) {

  $entity = $field['entity'];
  $content = $entity->type;
  $class = $entity->type;
```

So the end result should be something like this:

```
<div class="field field--name-type-label field--type-ds CONTENTTYPE">...</div>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time Display Suite is used in content output, it's wrapped in an `<article>` element with the content type as a class. You can see below that the content type can be found as `node-enterprise-blog` class.

[image: Display Suite Content Type Class]

I'm not sure what your end purpose for this is, but this way you can select the element using `.node-enterprise-blog .field-field-name`. If you need to add a class to the field, consider using the **Field Template** option under DS Extras. It allows you to change the markup of each field in a view mode.

Comment: You're right, I didn't spot the node-FIELDNAME class the first time, thanks for pointing it out. If someoneis reading this, and wants a class on the field itself, you can do this by wrapping the content, like so: `$content = '<div class="' . $entity->type . '">' . $entity->type . '</div>';`